# Elastic Beanstalk ModuleNotFoundError Flask App

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my flask app to EB. My current structure is as follows:

```
requirements.txt
backend/
   __init__.py
   application.py
   configurations/
      __init__.py
```

With the core part of my `application.py` looking something like

```
from flask import Flask

from backend import configurations

application = Flask(__name__)
```

I have also set the `WSGI` path within beanstalk to point to my `backend/application.py` file as such[image]

However, my issue occurs when deploying. EB logs the following error when building which causes my app to be degraded

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'
```

It looks like something to do with the module importing but I'm not sure where to go from here as doing something like `FLASK_APP=backend.application python3 -m flask run` works locally

Comment: Did you try with just `import configurations`?

Comment: My issue was something to do with a stray `__init__.py` that was messing up the module scope. Not an EB issue but not sure why this wasn't appearing locally. Thank you for the suggestion though @Marcin